Mysql RC-transaction, why exists gap-locks?
Same issue: in my opinion, the Gap Lock only appears during RR transactions in MySQL. However, when I try to reproduce the situation, it just disappears. Has anyone else come across this situation?
I want to understand the underlying principle of this behavior.
